# Using Sphinx to write personal websites and blogs

Tags: python, plugins, web, blogs, python-sphinx

[Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) is a Python library to generate nice documentation from a set of [ReST](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) formatted text files.

I wonder if any one has written Sphinx plugins to make it **generate personal websites and blogs**.

Especially for blogs, there needs to be a way to automatically list posts chronologically and generate a RSS feed. One needs to write a Sphinx plugin to do such special page/xml generation.

Has anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've done it at http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog. The key trick is to add a preprocessor step.  I've got my blog entries in a `weblog/yyyy/mm/dd/` folder structure.

A script iterates through that folder structure, creating `index.txt` files in every directory, listing the sub-items.  The normal Sphinx process then renders those `index.txt` files.

I added a custom Sphinx processor for tags.  So ".. tags:: python, buildout" somewhere at the top of my weblog entry generates the tags.  And the preprocessor again collects those entries and writes out a `weblog/tags/TAGNAME.txt` file which Sphinx again renders normally.

The preprocessor also creates the root `weblog/index.txt` with the latest 10 entries.  And an `weblog/atom.xml` in (hardcoded) the output directory for the rss feed.

So: you need some custom stuff, but it is pretty much plain text, so for me it was a nice exercise.  And you get to write some helper scripts to make life easy, for instance one that copies a textfile from somewhere to today's weblog directory (including creation of missing directories and an "svn add").

Comment: Can you sure your tag solution?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson: yes, see http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2012/01/22/website-changes.html#sphinx-as-weblog-code-is-now-available-somewhat . Custom made and partially hardcoded. Feel free to copy/paste. I might clean it up into a library one day, but I've been thinking that for two years now, so I'm not making a fixed promise right now :-)

Answer (score 14):

As of now (February, 2012), there are different resources available to do what you want:

A blog engine based on sphinx: http://tinkerer.me/

Reinout Van Rees' blog: https://github.com/reinout/reinout.vanrees.org

The feed contrib extension: https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/src/tip/feed/README

Answer (score 14):

If you need to write in [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) , you should try [Pelican](http://docs.getpelican.com/).

Pelican is a static site generator, written in Python. You'll be able to write your blog entries directly in reStructuredText or Markdown.

Answer (score 13):

Doug hellmann, author of the 'Python Module of the Week' does his site using Sphinx.

http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/

He has several posts which cover sphinx topics that can probably help you on your way:

[http://blog.doughellmann.com](http://doughellmann.com/?s=sphinx)

Answer (score 10):

Check out [ABlog for Sphinx](http://ablog.readthedocs.org/)

I am in the process of starting a blog myself using it.

I stumbled across it while I was going through my feeds in feedly. I searched about it and found it interesting. It also has Disqus integration, and can generat Atom feeds (not very sure what that is at the moment, I am new to the web)

I have not yet figured out how to deploy my test blog, will update when i find out something.

Comment: I have edited your question bacuse the way it was written smelled like spam. Maybe you can [edit] it further and explain *why* it would be a good solution for the OP? Does it e.g. generate RSS as he/she asked? Just a link is not enough.

Comment: hmm, ABlog is actually the best answer. Compared to tinkerer, It is more actively maintained and allows posts to be tagged using rst rather then relying on folder hierarchy. It supports RSS feeds, font awesome, Disqus and [many other features](http://ablog.readthedocs.org/manual/ablog-configuration-options).

Answer (score 7):

It's worth knowing that there is an RSS extension for sphinx in the sphinx-contrib extensions, called `sphinxcontrib.feed`
It and many other fun Sphinx things live at http://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/

(Disclaimer: I wrote the feed extension.)

Answer (score 3):

Not Sphinx, but several of the sites at http://codespeak.net/ are done with scripts that take ReST text, generates HTML and uploads them to the site. I didn't write those scripts though, but I've used them.

It's a reasonable way to generate sites if the sites need to contain a lot of ReST files anyway, like when generating documentation for python modules, which of course these sites are all about. It's also good if you need the site to be version controlled, because you can keep the source code in svn or hg, or something.

But if you start writing a lot of automatic menues and other extensions, what you will end up with in the end is a content management system. And there is plenty of those around already, so you might want to look at them first.

Another example is the new packages.python.org. There you can generate your documentation in anyway you want it, and then through PyPI upload a zip-file with the docs. Distribute has done this with Sphinx: http://packages.python.org/distribute . But there no particular script is needed, that's just generating HTML from Sphinx documentation.

However...

I must say that I find the idea of writing a blogging software as Sphinx extension a bit funny, especially since there is so much excellent blogging software out there already. And nothing is going to beat Wordpress anyway, and wordpress.com has been a great blogging experience for me. But as an exercise in how much you can abuse Sphinx, why not! :-)

Comment: Using Sphinx over Wordpress has the advantage that your articles are just plain text, which can be written in your favorite editor, put under version control, can be grepped, syntax-highlighted, etc.

Comment: And Wordpress code highlighting is terrible for python, in my experience, whereas in Sphinx, it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I redid my personal website (http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/steve/) in Sphinx.  It works nicely.  *Sadly, the SO markup mangles the `_` in my URL.*

I also rewrote the entire *Introduction to Programming for Non-Programmers* (http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/books/nonprog/html/index.html) book in Sphinx.  I'm in the process of rewriting Introduction to Python in Sphinx.

I do not use Sphinx for blogs -- it's not perfectly convenient, but it would work.  I use [blogspot](http://slott-softwarearchitect.blogspot.com/) for low-graphics/high-text and relatively high-velocity blogging. I use iWeb (http://web.me.com/s_lott/Travel/Welcome.html) for high graphic and relatively low-velocity blogging.

Comment: The first two links are broken!

Comment: Silly SO markup mangles the _'s.  I think I have them fixed.  The point is that I use Sphinx heavily.